# Modify entityframework query to bring specific fields in a multiple level select

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have three model classes in my code-first model.

```
public class Project
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public guid ProjectTypeId{ get; set; }
    public string projectType{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime CreationDate{ get; set; }
    //more properties here
    //...
    public bool Activated{ get; set; }
    public IList<ProjectDetail> ProjectDetails{ get; set; }
}
```

As you can see a project has many details.

```
public class ProjectDetail
{
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Project Project{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Guid ProjectId{ get; set; }             
    public string DetailDescription{ get; set; }
    public IList<ProjectDetailsAnswer> ProjectDetailsAnswers{ get; set; }
}
```

And a projectDetail has many answers:

```
public class ProjectDetailsAnswer
{
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Guid ProjectDetailId{ get; set; }
    public ProjectDetail ProjectDetail{ get; set; }       
    public string OtherField{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(512)]
    public string AnswerDescription{ get; set; }
}
```

This is my query so far:

```
var result = _dbContext.Project//<==search from details
    .Include(x => x.ProjectDetail)
    .Include(y => y.ProjectDetail.Select( c=> c.ProjectDetailAnswer))
    }).ToList();
```

My questions are the following please>

1. How do I modify the entity framework query to bring

> Project.Id,list of projectDetail.DetailDescription that contains all ProjectDetailsAnswer.AnswerDescription.

2. A suggestion for a viewmodel that can contain the results from the query in question 1.

Comment: As a side note: `[Required]` is not needed for value types like `Guid` and `DateTime`, Entity Framework already makes them required.

Comment: ... when they're not nullable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a ViewModel such as:

```
public class ProjectViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    // this could be a Dictionary<string, List<string>> 
    // if there are no duplicate DetailDescription's for a Project 
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>> Details { get; set; }
}
```

Your query would then look something like this:

```
var data = _dbContext.Project
    .Select(p => new ProjectViewModel
    {
        Id = p.Id,
        Details = p.ProjectDetails
            .Select(pd => new KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>(pd.DetailDescription, pd.ProjectDetailsAnswers.Select(pda => pda.AnswerDescription).ToList()))
            .ToList()
    })
   .ToList();
```

Comment: thanks, but what happens if there are duplicated details?

Comment: @deedee This will work just fine. It wouldn't if you used a `Dictionary`

Comment: I am getting an error in the new KeyValuePair: >>does not contain a constructor that takes that many arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a hierarchy of view models:

```
public class ProjectViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    private List<ProjectDetailViewModel> _details = new List<ProjectDetailViewModel>();    
    public List<ProjectDetailViewModel> Details 
    { 
        get {return _details; }
        set {_details = value; } 
    }
}

public class ProjectDetailViewModel
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}

private List<AnswerViewModel> _answers = new List<AnswerViewModel>();    
    public List<AnswerViewModel> Answers 
    { 
        get {return _answers; }
        set {_answers = value; } 
    }
}

public class AnswerViewModel
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
}
```

Then

```
List<ProjectViewModel> result = _dbContext.Projects
    .Where(x => /* conditions */)
    .Select(x => new ProjectViewModel
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Details = x.ProjectDetails.Select(d => new ProjectDetailViewModel
        {
            Id = d.Id,
            Description = d.Description,
            Answers = d.ProjectDetailAnswers.Select(a => new AnswerViewModel
            { 
                Id = a.Id,
                Description = a.Description
            }
        }
    }).ToList();
```

This will compose a query against the DB that just returns the selected fields and composes the project with a list of details with the relevant answers.

If you want to flatten it to just have a list of answers under the project (with the detail description included in the answer.)

```
public class ProjectViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    private List<ProjectDetailAnswertViewModel> _answers = new List<ProjectDetailAnswertViewModel>();    
    public List<ProjectDetailAnswertViewModel> Answers
    { 
        get {return _answers; }
        set {_answers = value; } 
    }
}

public class ProjectDetailAnswertViewModel
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public string DetailDescription {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
}
```

Then

```
List<ProjectViewModel> result = _dbContext.Project
    .Where(x => /* conditions */)
    .Select(x => new ProjectViewModel
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Answers = x.ProjectDetails.SelectMany(d => d.ProjectDetailAnswers).Select(a => new ProjectDetailAnswerViewModel
        {
            Id = a.Id,
            DetailDescription = a.ProjectDetail.Description,
            Description = a.Description,
        }
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Why are you explicitly declaring backing fields? You don't need those

Comment: I declare backing fields for collections so that in cases where I am declaring new entities the collections are ready to go and accept new children instead of initializing as #null. I believe with C#7 you can  initialize the property with something like public List<T> MyTs {get; set;} => new List<T>(); but I haven't played around with that yet and just in the process of upgrading a new client's system to a modern environment.

Comment: The common way in Entity Framework is to just initialize the collections in the constructor

Comment: Tomäto, tomàto. :)